# How to generate subtitle while audio is being played in react native application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio-streaming, caption

I am creating a demo where I want a functionality to show subtitles/captions of the audio playing from the same application. It is like youtube when the video is playing and we are able to see the subtitles/captions but I want it for audio. I have checked many things but have not been able to find anything useful.

Comment: Do you have subtitle files? if so, what format?

Comment: @MarekLisik No, I do not have subtitle files as it needs to be directly shown subtitle from the audio itself.

Comment: Then the actual question is not how to show subtitles but how to generate them. Not something I can weigh in on much.

Comment: @MarekLisik I have changed it. Thanks for suggesting.